# Spring java based config ResourceLoader

Tags: spring-mvc

I am new to java-based configuration in spring.  I am trying to convert the xml based configuration found here: https://github.com/sps/mustache-spring-view

My problem is the ResourceLoader used by MustacheViewResolver is throwing a null pointer exception.  How can I properly load the resource loader provided by spring into this configuration?

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = Application.class, includeFilters = @Filter(Controller.class), useDefaultFilters = false)
class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
    @Bean
    public MustacheViewResolver viewResolver() {
        MustacheViewResolver resolver = new MustacheViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/mustache/");
        resolver.setSuffix("hbs");
        resolver.setCache(true);

        resolver.setTemplateFactory(new MustacheJTemplateFactory());
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.mustache.java.MustacheJTemplateFactory.getReader(MustacheJTemplateFactory.java:71)
```

And the line from MustacheJTemplateFactory

```
Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource(resourceName);
```

Please Note: I believe this to be a general question about spring java configuration, and not a specific question about the library I am using.  I could be wrong though!

Answer (score 1):

Autowire in the Spring resource loader:

```
@Autowired
ResourceLoader resourceLoader;
```

Then set it in your viewResolver() function:

```
MustacheJTemplateFactory factory = new MustacheJTemplateFactory();
factory.setResourceLoader(resourceLoader);
resolver.setTemplateFactory(factory);
```